# VBScript Saving excel file as new type with original name

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2003

I have this code, it all works fine, but I cannot figure out how to get it to keep the original filename:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = False
app.DisplayAlerts = False

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("F:\Billing_Common\autoemail").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xlsx" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
filename = f
wb.SaveAs "F:\Billing_Common\autoemail\filename.xls", -4143
wb.Close SaveChanges=True

  End if
Next

app.Quit
Set app = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to keep the basename and just change the extension? That can be achieved like this:

```
newname = fso.BuildPath(wb.Path, fso.GetBaseName(wb.Name) & ".xls")
wb.SaveAs newname, -4143
```

If you want to delete the old file afterwards, you can do it like this:

```
f.Delete True
```

I'd do this after closing the workbook, just to be on the safe side.

---

BTW, I already told you that

```
wb.Close SaveChanges=True
```

doesn't do what you seem to think it does. Use just

```
wb.Close True
```

without the parameter name.

Comment: Thanks i've got it now, is there any way to delete the original file after i've saved the new one?